# How to avoid sub-menu mixing when hovering too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code :

```
<ul class="navigation-links">
                    <li class="link-item">
                        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_04.png" width="150" height="41" alt="" />
                        <div style="display: none" class="sub-menu">
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/home.png" width="46" height="14" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/home.png" width="46" height="14" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                     <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/sataer.png" width="124" height="17" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link-item">
                        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_03.png" width="154" height="41" alt="" />
                        <div style="display:none" class="sub-menu index-menu-col2">
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/decor.png" width="53" height="15" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                  <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/acc.png" width="94" height="15" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                  <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/out-decor.png" width="120" height="17" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link-item">
                        <img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_02.png" width="152" height="41" alt="" />
                        <div style="display: none" class="sub-menu index-menu-col3">
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/lighting.png" width="35" height="16" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                  <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                            <div class="sub-col">
                                <img src="images/new-menu/electric.png" width="106" height="19" alt="" />
                                <ul>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                                    <li>item</li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link-item"><img src="images/new-menu/menu-item_01.png" width="151" height="41" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
```

and this JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".link-item").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown("slow");
});
$(".link-item").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast");
});
```

});

This menu is working just fine but when hovering too fast on the menu bar, each menu will appear and disappear quickly and it will look very ugly.

I think the solution will be to stop slide down event until all slide up event stops but I don't know how to do it.

If there is any other solution, I am ready to try it.

[Demo Website](http://www.mfrsht.com/demo/demo.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). It does some logic to make sure your hover seemed intentional, like slowing down over the item, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code. Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".link-item").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop(true,false).slideDown("slow");
});
$(".link-item").mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").stop(true,false).slideUp("fast");
});

});
```